# jQuery Table Sorting Plugin Suggestions?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm interested in building something that requires a table sorting plugin.

Best way to think of it, is imagine you wanted to build MS Outlook online, the structure is something like this:

```
Subject | Date&Time | Unread
lots of rows
lots of rows
lots of rows
```

I'd like a jQuery Table Sorting plugin, that allows me to use the header to do the following:

- Can Click the header item to toggle ASC/DESC
- Can Resize the Columns

After googling, I haven't found any that do both well. I did try ingrid, but when you resize a column the page flashes (it isn't pretty) so that's not good.

Suggestions from actual experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) does well for what it says it does. Not sure about resizing columns with the mouse - you might have add that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few jQuery plugins that enable sortable tables, but I'm not familiar with any that allow dynamically resizable columns.

I've used [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) in the past and liked it. It doesn't (currently) allow you to resize the columns with the mouse, but it can [adjust the column widths](http://datatables.net/api) at rendering time based on the length of the text in the table cells. (See the fnAdjustColumnSizing configuration option)

Answer (score 0):

Use [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki).  ([Demo](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html))

The huge benefit of SlickGrid is that it creates and removes DOM elements on the fly as the user scrolls.  This allows you to display literally hundereds of thousands of records with no noticeable performance penalties.